# returning a list from a recursive function using python

Tags: python, list, recursion

```
 def helper(candidates, strt, target, arry):
    
    if target == 0:
        return arry
    if target < 0:
        return 
    for i in range(strt, len(candidates)):
        arry.append(candidates[i])
        helper(candidates, i, target-candidates[i], arry)
        arry.remove(candidates[i])
    return arry

coll = []
candidates = [2,3,6,7]
target = 7

coll = helper(candidates, 0, target, coll)
```

I am getting empty list when i print the coll in the main function
I want to return all the appended value in arry from helper function.
How can i do that.

Comment: What is `self`?  That variable is not defined.

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do, overall? Maybe it is empty because you call remove over all elements?

Comment: trying to find all the values that adds up to the target (7). I am supposed to get arry = [[2,2,3], [7]] - Thank You